# How do I remove the term ID from the view URL?

Tags: views, 8, uri

I have a content view with an exposed filter based on a vocabulary.

In the URL (for example, mysite/myview?tid=taxonomy+term+(3)), and incidentally in my page title (I use argument.tid to display a title based on the term typed in the exposed filter), there are the name of the term (perfect) but also the term ID.

I only need mysite/myview?tid=taxonomy+term or, better, mysite/taxonomy-term.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can do this using htaccess rules.

You can probably apply the patch from [this issue](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/118072) and than according to the reports you will be able to create a path alias from within drupal that accept url parameters (as in your case)

But you can also try [views_url_path_arguments](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_url_path_arguments) which seems to be usable in Drupal 8 judging from the amount of downloads.

Perhaps you can also give this sandbox module [Query Parameters To Url](https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/utkarsh-dixit/2842440) a try

Note: I have not tested the above 2 modules

Comment: thanks GiorgosK, do you have an example of rewrite rules in htaccess? I'm looking for but find nothing conclusive

Comment: Not tested but try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40109617/rewrite-url-not-working-in-htaccess-drupal-8

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Better Exposed Filters](https://www.drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters) Module, it's useful module, in drupal 8 still alpha version but.

> Drupal 8:
>   The Drupal 8 branch is in active development. If you have immediate need of a specific feature in BEF, please contact a maintainer to discuss sponsorship. BEF will work best if you are at least using Drupal 8.3 and you should be using newer.
>
> ✓ Recommended by the project’s maintainer.

Comment: thanks berramou, I do not find how to modify the url with BEF, do you know how to do?